# How to send Attachment through email library using own email library in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, email-attachments

If I code below method in my own library, it is sending email successfully but attachments are not shown in email i.e., attachments are not attached with email, also on enabling bcc, it throws Internal Server Error but if i use same code in my controller its working properly.

```
public function sendEmail($arrData=array()){
        if($arrData['TO_EMAIL']=='') return FALSE;
        $status = FALSE;
        $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'sendmail',
            'charset'   => 'utf-8',
            'wordwrap'  => TRUE,
            'mailtype'  => 'html'
        );
        $to = 'ra@gmail.com';
        $cci =& get_instance();
        $cci->load->library('email', $config);

        $cci->email->from($arrData['FROM_EMAIL'],           $arrData['FROM_NAME']);
        $cci->email->to($arrData['TO_EMAIL'], $arrData['TO_NAME']);
        if($arrData['CC_EMAIL'])
            $cci->email->cc($arrData['CC_EMAIL']);
        //$this->email->bcc('ravr@rediffmail.com');
        $cci->email->subject($arrData['SUBJECT']);
        $cci->email->message($arrData['MESSAGE']);
        if($arrData['FILES'])
            $cci->email->attach($arrData['FILES']);
        $status = $cci->email->send();
        return $status;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by your own library? the codeigniter email library or?

Comment: I've created various modules for Agreements instead of repeating email codes in all controller I've created a library for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the path helper

```
$this->load->helper('path');
$path = set_realpath('pathtouploads'); //your uploads folder
```

then

```
$this->email->attach($path . $file);
```

Comment: Bcc : `$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');`

Comment: I've tested it with $this->email->bcc('ravr@rediffmail.com'); and $this->email->bcc(array('ravr@rediffmail.com'));  but I received Internal Server Error

Comment: I created model instead of library and all is working well